# Ignite performing slow on cluster

Tags: ignite

We are using ignite JDBC thin driver to store 1 million records in a table on ignite cache.
To insert 1 Million records on single node it take 60 sec, where as on cluster of 2 nodes it takes 5 min and time grows exponentially as number of nodes are increased.

attached ignite log file where time was consumed on cluster.
attached configuration file for the cluster.
[The log and configuration file is here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1x0qdBMDyjYEaJI-UF17kif63uLPJKq94)

IS there any additional configuration required to get time down to insert records over a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you always test networked configuration.

You should avoid testing "client and server on the same machine" configuration because it can not be compared with "two server nodes on different machines". And it certainly should not be compared with "two server nodes on the same machine" :)

I've heard that thin JDBC driver is not optimized yet for fast INSERTs. Please try client-node JDBC driver with batching (via `PreparedStatement.addBatch()`).

Comment: Yes, We have client on different machine and cluster nodes are also on different machines. Right now we are using addBatch to insert the records. We will try using client node jdbc. 
Thanks

Comment: We have tried using jdbs node driver but it took more time than jdbc thin driver i.e around 6 min

Comment: I recommend sending this case on userlist: https://ignite.apache.org/community/resources.html
Please provide code sample, nodes and caches configurations so that community can look into your inquiry in-depth.